# Copying a slice into a reflected array

Tags: reflection, go, struct

I have a structure that looks like this:

```
type Record struct {
   Name         string
   QuestionType [2]byte // Array may be arbitrary length
   Class        [3]byte
}
```

I am attempting to fill the structure with bytes from a `bytes.Buffer` (I am unable to use binary.Read due to some additional complexity in the byte data.) I'm using the `reflect` package to iterate over the elements of the structure, and read from the bytes.Buffer into the structure.

```
func fillStructure(buffer *bytes.Buffer) *Record {
   // This is hard-coded now, but will be passed in as an interface later
   myStruct := Record{}
   reflectedStruct := reflect.ValueOf(&myStruct).Elem()

   for i := 0; i < reflectedStruct.NumField(); i++ {
      field := reflectedStruct.Field(i)

      if field.Kind() == reflect.Array {
         // Copy bytes from buffer into structure
      }
   }

   return &myStruct
}
```

However, when I attempt to fill the [n]byte arrays with n bytes from the buffer, I find myself unable to copy the slice returned by `buffer.Next(n)` into the array in the struct.

- `field.Set()` doesn't work because []byte is incompatible with [n]byte.
- `copy()` doesn't work because I can't find a way to get a slice of the struct's array

**Question**: Is there a way to get a slice "view" of the reflected structure's array so I can copy the values in? Or some other way to copy the slice returned by buffer into the structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`copy` does work if you "trick" the array into thinking it's a slice.

```
copy(myStruct.QuestionType[:], buffer.Bytes())
```

In your case, you can use `reflect.Copy` together with the above technique like so:

```
if field.Kind() == reflect.Array {
    srcArr := [2]byte{}
    copy(srcArr[:], buffer.Bytes())
    reflect.Copy(field, reflect.ValueOf(srcArr))
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's certainly farther than I got. However, I can't declare a srcArray of length `field.Len()`. The structure's array may not always be of length 2, and I need to read however many bytes are necessary. Sorry if that wasn't clear, I'll update the question.

Comment: Turns out if I use `srcArr := make([]byte, field.Len())` to make the slice, `reflect.Copy` can copy that slice into the structure. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Yes, your method of `srcArr := make([]byte, field.Len())` creates an equivalent of  `srcArr[:]`. You mind ticking my answer as the right one since there's no other?